# GridView item animation does not work after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-gridview

I set animation to one item of gridView and it works fine, but after notifyDataSetChanged the animation does not work.

```
gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter (context, myArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animation);


gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int i, long l) {

//change myArray items

gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 view.startAnimation(animation);
}
});
```

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` method tells adapter to drop current references and load all things from the start. So, you won't be seeing any animations with this method. `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemUpdated()` these methods lets you properly and efficiently update data. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter. Read more about adapters. Also, a much better way would be to use DiffUtils to calculate any change. Much better than above-mentioned methods.

Comment: I am using BaseAdapter, do notifyItemInserted() and notifyItemUpdated() work for BaseAdapter?